# How to translate this cURL call into PHP?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

How do I express the equivalent in PHP?

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "App-Key:APP_KEY" -X POST "https://api.address" -d '<credentials><partnerId>PARTNER_ID</partnerId><partnerSecret>PARTNER_SECRET</partnerSecret></credentials>'
```

What I have is the following, which is not working.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://api.address');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/xml', 'App-Key:APP_KEY'));     

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('<credentials><partnerId>PARTNER_ID</partnerId><partnerSecret>PARTNER_SECRET</partnerSecret></credentials>'));                   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Only error I get is 'couldn't connect to host'. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

`$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.address');`

also notice, that url is https, try also with following:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`